# How to pronounce the second last unaccented "о" sound, as in "слишком", "самом"?

Tags: произношение

> слишк**о**м рано
>
> на сам**о**м деле

These "о"s correspond to the IPA "**ə**". I seem to notice some speakers pronounce it like the *pure* "**o**" sound, as in "**о**н" or "д**о**лг", albeit unstressed, while others make it sound more like "**a**", as in "ран**о**", "какой-т**о**".

Comment: The two vowels are pronounced exactly the same, as [ə], both in the Russian and in the English words.

Comment: if someone pronounces their ***unstressed*** **O** as **O** in **"он"** or **"долг"** (which is ***stressed***) that would be **оканье** (o-ing), which isn't the standard modern Russian pronunciation but which still exists among older population in some remote regions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you hear them say "[с лишк**о**м](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)" (meaning a little more than needed) and "[сам**о**м](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC)" (prepositional case of "сам" meaning "oneself").